# Invalid Protocol Buffer schema. Import "google/protobuf/any.proto" has not been loaded: GCP/Pub-Sub

Tags: schema, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub, proto

I am new to GCP. I am trying to use Pub/Sub service with schema definition using protobuf.

Schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message Endorsement {
  string endorserId=1;
  google.protobuf.Any data = 2;
  string signature=3;
  bool isVerified=4;
}

message TransactionPayload {
  string policyId =1;
  string txnId =2;
  repeated Endorsement endorsements=3;
}
```

Validation of this schema fails with an error

> Invalid Protocol Buffer schema. Import "google/protobuf/any.proto" has
> not been loaded.

[image]

I need to use google.protobuf.Any, is there any other way to use/define this?

Comment: How do you validate this? Which API are you using?

Comment: I am using GCP console's functionality to define and validate the schema using GCP portal (Web UI) added screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, imports are not supported with Pub/Sub's schema support. You'd have to define the message type yourself in the definition for your message type. Note also that the current schema support only allows a single message top-message type to be defined, so you'd also have to embed the `Endorsement` definition inside the `TransactionPayload` definition.

Comment: ohh that's sad. This forces me to move to a different solution for messaging. Thanks for your support. Could you please add some references in the answer pointing to things supported/unsupported by pub/sub at the moment?

Comment: It turns out this limitation is not mentioned in the documentation yet. Will make sure it is added to https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/schemas.